# MouseListener in separate class not working

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have separate class to handle mouse listener. But it not working when I use it from another class and I don't know yet how to solve this. Here my Handler class:

```
some import stuff

public class Handler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
private final Canvas canvas;

public Handler(Canvas targetCanvas) {
    this.canvas = targetCanvas;
}

// recasting exception
public Canvas getTargetCanvas() {
    return canvas;
}
...
...
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // recasting exception
    DrawingCanvas dC = (DrawingCanvas) getTargetCanvas();
    dC.setMouseDragged(true);
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // recasting exception
    DrawingCanvas dCanvas = (DrawingCanvas) getTargetCanvas();
    dCanvas.setMouseClicked(true);
    dCanvas.setMouseCoordinates(e.getPoint());
}
}
```

DrawingCanvas class:

```
some import stuff

public class DrawingCanvas extends Canvas {
private boolean isMouseDragged, isMouseMoved;
private Point mouseCoordinates;

public DrawingCanvas() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(790, 500));
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

public Point getMouseCoordinates() {
    return mouseCoordinates;
}

public boolean isIsMouseDragged() {
    return isMouseDragged;
}

public boolean isIsMouseMoved() {
    return isMouseMoved;
}
...
...
public void setMouseDragged(boolean dragged) {
    isMouseDragged = dragged;
}

public void setMouseMoved(boolean moved) {
    isMouseMoved = moved;
}

public void setMouseCoordinates(Point coordinates) {
    mouseCoordinates = coordinates;
}
}
```

StatusBar class:

```
some import stuff

public class StatusBar extends JPanel {
private JLabel statusBar;

public StatusBar() {
    statusBar = new JLabel();

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
    this.setBackground(new Color(242,241,240));
    this.add(statusBar, new BorderLayout(5,0));

}

public JLabel getStatusBar() {
    return statusBar;
}

public void setStatusBar(JLabel statusBar) {
    this.statusBar = statusBar;
}
}
```

And MouseEventGUI class:

```
some import stuff

public class MouseEventGUI extends JFrame {
private DrawingCanvas drawingCanvas;
private StatusBar statusBar;
private MenuBar menuBar;

public MouseEventGUI() {
    super("Learn Mouse Event");

    drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas();
    statusBar = new StatusBar();
    menuBar = new MenuBar();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 560));

    this.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(drawingCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);       
    this.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.addMouseListener(new Handler(drawingCanvas));
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new Handler(drawingCanvas));

    if(drawingCanvas.isIsMouseMoved()){
        statusBar.getStatusBar().setText(String.format("%d, %d", 
                drawingCanvas.getMouseCoordinates().x, 
                drawingCanvas.getMouseCoordinates().y));
    } else {
        statusBar.getStatusBar().setText("Mouse is not listened.");
    }    
}
}
```

when i run the program, in status bar show "Mouse is not listened" (see in MouseEventGUI class) that I wish it show the coordinates of mouse cursor if I moved it in canvas.

**[update]**

if in the same class, it **work well** with some modification. Here the code for DrawingCanvas class:

```
public class DrawingCanvas extends JPanel {
private boolean isMouseClicked,
        isMouseMoved;
private Point mouseCoordinates;
protected StatusBar statusBar;
protected MenuBar menuBar;


public DrawingCanvas(StatusBar st) {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(790, 500));
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    statusBar = st;
    Handlers handlers = new Handlers();
    addMouseListener(handlers);
    addMouseMotionListener(handlers);
}

**// inner class**
protected class Handlers extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        statusBar.getStatusBar().setText("Mouse clicked.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {            
        statusBar.getStatusBar().setText(String.format("%d, %d", e.getX(),e.getY()));

    }

}
}
```

and here for MouseEventGUI class:

```
public class MouseEventGUI extends JFrame {
private DrawingCanvas drawingCanvas;
private StatusBar statusBar;
private MenuBar menuBar;

public MouseEventGUI() {
    super("Learn Mouse Event");

    statusBar = new StatusBar();
    menuBar = new MenuBar();
    drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas(statusBar);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 560));
    this.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(drawingCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);       
    this.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

But, I plan to make it in separate class for **reusable** reason.

Comment: Please define for us what you mean by "it not working"? You've dumped a lot of code and provided very little description. Please help us be more knowledgeable about your code and your problem so we can have a better chance of being able to help you. As an aside: why AWT and not Swing? Also, your MouseListener doesn't appear to be doing anything measurable.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I've up date my posting

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Does it work if it is in the ***same*** class?  That is something you should check first.  The `KeyListener` class is notorious for failing.  Also, for Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Comment: Shouldn't the listener be added to the drawing canvas and not to `this`? You probably want to listen to mouse events happening on the canvas, not on the frame.

Comment: @ Andrew, I've make it in the same class. But i plan to make Handler class reusable, it must be in separate class?

Comment: OK, but a separate class can still be included in an MCVE.  To do that (temporarily) demote the access from `public` (to anything less) and simply paste it in the end of the source code of the class with `main(String[])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendations:

- Yes, make Handler a completely separate independent class.
- Yes, get your listened-to component via the MouseEvent's `getSource()` method. You can check if it's the right type of object before casting by using the `instanceof` operator but if you always and only add it to one type of object, then this isn't an issue.
- Yes, as Camickr and others suggests, don't use AWT's Canvas but rather Swing's JPanel. There are traps that can happen if you mix AWT and Swing components together, you lose a lot of functionality if you use AWT instead of Swing, and there's no need to use Canvas.
- I would have the MouseListener (in my code, I used a MouseAdapter since it can allow slightly more compact code with less unnecessary code such as empty methods) change the state of the listened to component by calling a setter method.
- I've had this work well by having that setter method change the state of a "bound" property, one that notifies any PropertyChangeListeners that are interested in its change.
- And I'd do just that -- add a PropertyChangeListener to the JPanel with the MouseListener and in it change the state of the status JPanel if mouse events occur.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HandlerTester extends JPanel {
   public HandlerTester() {
      Handler handler = new Handler();
      final MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
      myPanel.addMouseListener(handler);
      myPanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

      final StatusPanel statusPanel = new StatusPanel();

      myPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (MyPanel.MOUSE_PRESSED.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               statusPanel.setMousePressed(((Boolean)pcEvt.getNewValue()).booleanValue());
            }
         }
      });

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      HandlerTester handlerTester = new HandlerTester();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("HandlerTester");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(handlerTester);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class Handler extends MouseAdapter {
   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
      Object src = mEvt.getSource();
      if (src instanceof MyPanel) {
         MyPanel myPanel = (MyPanel) src;
         myPanel.setMousePressed(true);         
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mEvt) {
      Object src = mEvt.getSource();
      if (src instanceof MyPanel) {
         MyPanel myPanel = (MyPanel) src;
         myPanel.setMousePressed(false);         
      }
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   public static final String MOUSE_PRESSED = "mouse pressed";
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private boolean mousePressed = false;

   public boolean isMousePressed() {
      return mousePressed;
   }

   public void setMousePressed(boolean mousePressed) {
      boolean oldValue = this.mousePressed;
      boolean newValue = mousePressed;
      this.mousePressed = mousePressed;
      firePropertyChange(MOUSE_PRESSED, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class StatusPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final String MOUSE_PRESSED = "Mouse Pressed";
   private static final String MOUSE_NOT_PRESSED = "Mouse Not Pressed";
   private JLabel label = new JLabel(MOUSE_NOT_PRESSED);

   public StatusPanel() {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
      add(label);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
   }

   public void setMousePressed(boolean mousePressed) {
      String text = mousePressed ? MOUSE_PRESSED : MOUSE_NOT_PRESSED;
      label.setText(text);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn your code. Can you give me some clue how to get myPanel coordinat in your code? I want to show the mouse cursor when it move in myPanel.

Comment: Use my ideas, but write your code. Coordinates are available from the MouseEvent parameter, `getX()`, `getY()`, and `getPoint()` work.